Equivalence between two tableaux in $SO(3)$?
I understand that for a given tableau in $SO(3)$, if a column has 3 boxes, that column can be removed using the Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon^{ijk}$. My question is whether a similar thing be done if a column has two boxes. If a column has two boxes, is it equivalent to a column with a single box? In particular, are the following two tableaux equivalent in $SO(3)$?
$$\begin{align}&\Box\,\,\,\Box\,\,\,\Box\,\,\,\sim\,\,\Box\,\,\,\Box\,\,\,\Box\\&\Box
\end{align}$$
In terms of tensors, this is equivalent to asking if a tensor $A^{i;jkl}$ with the mixed symmetry of the first tableau can always be written in terms of a tensor $B^{ijk}$ with the symmetry of the second tableau? Something like $A^{i;jkl}=\epsilon^{ijn}B^{nkl}$?

My sense is that the very rightmost box, and thus your index $l$, are superfluous. You are asking if $A^{i (jk)}-A^{j(ik)}=2\epsilon^{ijn} B^{(nk)}$. Dot both sides by $\epsilon^{ijm}$.

Hi fewfew4. This is about $SO(3)$; not $SU(3)$?

Thanks for helping me, this is about $SO(3)$. Doing what @CosmasZachos suggests, it looks like my guess is incorrect. But, is it possible to write $A^{i;jkl}$ in terms of lower rank irreducible reps using $\epsilon^{ijk}$?

Linked.

I'm surprised the first comment wasn't "yes". The usual convention is that $SO(N)$ tableaux have $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$ rows for exactly the reason you mention.

Thanks @Connor Behan, yes I was aware of this relation, but for some reason I am having a difficulty of explicitly writing the relation in terms of tensors when the tableaux are beyond 1 column.

In fact, SO(3) ~ SU(2), so think of SU(2) tableaux.
